# Rename to exif date: Unique filenames without creating duplicate files

Tags: command-line, exif

I recently posted a question about how to rename image filenames in a stable way to the exif date:

[Exiv2 rename: Make unique filenames](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/395428/5289)

This is a follow up question to it:

How can I *additionally* to the requirements in my first post make sure that no duplicate files are created. Consider for example three files `fileA.jpg`, `fileB.jpg`, `fileC.jpg`.

Suppose that `fileA.jpg` and `fileB.jpg` have the same exif time, say `2017:09:30 20:12:31` but are *different* images, i.e. not bitwise identical files. `fileC.jpg` however is the same as `fileA.jpg`.

Now if I apply the renaming command to the directory containing those files, I want to get:

- `2017_09_30__20_12_31.jpg` (from `fileA.jpg`)
- `2017_09_30__20_12_31-1.jpg` (from `fileB.jpg`)

And `fileC.jpg` should be deleted, since it is bitwise the same as `fileA.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two jobs:

- Delete duplicates
- Rename files

An easy way to remove duplicates is by installing `fdupes` first and run it in current directory:

```
fdupes ./ --delete --noprompt
```

The first time you might want to run it without `--noprompt`.

(In the link to *Exiv2 rename: Make unique filenames* you did not flagged the answer which solved your problem. Pls do.)